# The Informix is not throwing error when trying to update a row which is not present?

Tags: c, informix

We are analyzing an Informix behavior in production. When trying to update a row which is not present the application is getting "-346: Could not update a row in the table" error in production.

However, when we try the same in the dev region, the application works fine.

Whether the Informix should throw error always when updating a row which is not present or is it configurable at Informix level?

The application is written in C and the corresponding update queries are present in the ".ec" program.

Also, is there any other way Informix throws a -346 error?

> Edit: The SQL is as follows:
>
> ```
> update <table> set serial_number = <number1> where serial_number = <number2>
> ```
>
> The SQL Error is:
>
> ```
>  Execute SQL ERROR
>
>     SQL CODE = -346
>     SQLERM =
>     SQLERRP =
>     SQLERRD[0] = 1
>     SQLERRD[1] = -100
>     SQLERRD[2] = 0
>     SQLERRD[3] = 1
>     SQLERRD[4] = 56
>     SQLERRD[5] = 0
>     SQLWARN =
> ```

Edit Again:

The source code is as follows:

```
const char *sql = "update table_not_named set serial_number = ? where serial_number = ?"; 

if ( prepared_sql == 0 )
{
    exec sql prepare update_sql from :sql;
    if ( sqlca.sqlcode != SQL_OK )
    {
        logSqlError( log_err, __func__, "Prepare" );
        return FAIL;
    }
    prepared_sql = 1;
}

exec sql execute update_sql using :db_new_serial_number, :db_old_serial_number;

if ( sqlca.sqlcode != SQL_OK )
{
    logSqlError( log_err, __func__, "Execute" );
    return FAIL;
}
```

Comment: Error -346 is not a problem with present/absent.  The instructions from `finderr -346` say _While the database server was processing an UPDATE, it received an
unexpected error. Check the accompanying ISAM error code for more
detailed information on the cause. Possible causes include hardware
errors and locking conflicts._  You'll need to track the ISAM error (`sqca.sqlerrd[1]` in ESQL/C) to get some more information; it should be an error number with absolute value between 100 and 199.  This probably means there is a problem of some sort on your production system.  Show the SQL.

Comment: Note that updating a non-existent row with a searched UPDATE should simply report zero rows updated successfully.  In a MODE ANSI database, you would get a status of 100 (SQLNOTFOUND) instead of 0 (no error).  If you're doing a WHERE CURRENT OF update and the row's gone missing, then there's something weird going on indeed — it shouldn't happen (because it means you didn't get a lock on the row when you selected it, but someone managed to delete the row even though you should have had it locked).  If you didn't use the FOR UPDATE clause, then the WHERE CURRENT OF should have specific error.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I have updated the SQL error too. We are not sure whether our Informix DB is created in ANSI MODE or not.

Comment: Probably not MODE ANSI; you have to say you wanted it, and you usually don't.

Comment: Well, the command inside the script for DB create is 
CREATE DATABASE $DATABASE_INFO IN $DATABASE_SPACE WITH LOG;
So, I assume out DB is not in MODE ANSI and the production might be in MODE ANSI.
Is that the reason why we don't see the error and in production they see the error?

Comment: No; that's a logged database created in a specific dbspace.  You should assume that the database in production is also non-ANSI.  You can tell whether it is MODE ANSI: connect to the database and run `COMMIT WORK`.  If it complains 'not in a transaction', it is a non-ANSI database.  If it accepts it without flinching, it is an ANSI database.

Comment: wow, thank you for that piece of information, the "commit work" did complained, which underlines this is a non-ANSI database. However, we have created an ANSI database for testing purpose and create temp table. But when we tried to update the row, in the command prompt, there was no complain (we tried dbaccess $DBNAME) and the "$?" showed as 0. So, whether the error comes only inside the ".ec" program?

Comment: Presumably, the SQL you show is created as a string and then executed?  You can't specify the table name as a parameter, so that must be handling in the string.  You could use placeholders for the two values and pass them to the `$EXECUTE prepared_statement USING :new_value, :old_value;` or equivalent.  The key point is you should not be seeing the error.  The fact that you see it in production and not in the test environment supports this.  I'd need to see a bit more of the code — in MCVE ([MCVE]) form.  That is, show us a simple ESQL/C program that connects and updates and fails with -346.

Comment: Thank you for the comments Jonanthan. I have added the snipped from the code. Let me know if this gives any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*The comments are getting too big to be comments — by quite a margin.*</sup>

Error -346 is not a problem with present/absent. The instructions from `finderr -346` say:

> While the database server was processing an UPDATE, it received an unexpected error. Check the accompanying ISAM error code for more detailed information on the cause. Possible causes include hardware errors and locking conflicts.

You'll need to track the ISAM error (sqca.sqlerrd[1] in ESQL/C) to get some more information; it should be an error number with absolute value between 100 and 199. This probably means there is a problem of some sort on your production system.

Note that updating a non-existent row with a searched UPDATE should simply report zero rows updated successfully. In a MODE ANSI database, you would get a status of 100 (SQLNOTFOUND) instead of 0 (no error). If you're doing a WHERE CURRENT OF update and the row's gone missing, then there's something weird going on indeed — it shouldn't happen (because it means you didn't get a lock on the row when you selected it, but someone managed to delete the row even though you should have had it locked). If you didn't use the FOR UPDATE clause, then the WHERE CURRENT OF should have a more specific error.

<sup>*At this point, the question was updated to show the error information.*</sup>

Curious message: I ran

```
create table sample
(
    serial_number integer not null primary key,
    value varchar(30) not null
);
insert into sample values(123, 'one hundred and twenty-three');
update sample set serial_number = 124 where serial_number = 99;
```

which gives a status of 0 (and reports 0 rows updated).   Your message has `-100` as the ISAM error; that's the message for 'ISAM error: duplicate value for a record with unique key'.

But when I try:

```
insert into sample values(99, 'ninety-nine');
update sample set serial_number = 123 where serial_number = 99;
```

I get error:

```
SQL -268: Unique constraint (jleffler.u160_350) violated.
ISAM -100: ISAM error:  duplicate value for a record with unique key.
```

That's about what I'd expect.  I note that you can't directly update a column of type SERIAL (or SERIAL8 or BIGSERIAL): you get `SQL -232: A SERIAL column (s) may not be updated` (where `s` was the name of the serial column I tried to update to generate the message — it's not a bad plural in the message).

Since the primary message for error -346 indicates that there could be a problem in the database, it would be worth running ON-Check ([`oncheck`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0369.htm)) on the system to see whether that table is all OK.  If you're not in the habit of running ON-Check, you'll need to look up the options.  I'd probably do some general checks (e.g. `oncheck -cr` to check the reserved pages) before going on to validate the table and the indexes where the problem is occurring (`oncheck -ci` and `oncheck -cd`).  It may be worth using `-cR`, `-cI`, `-cD` options to get more information.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I don't have permission to run "oncheck" and requested for the DBA assistance. Your explanation helped to pass the message on how serious the issue could be. Thanks again and I will update the error I get from the above commands.

Comment: Fair enough.  Can you repro the problem with other tables, or just with the one table?  Can you create a similar table in the production database and run into the problem?

Comment: I don't have production access and cant do much R&D there due to the huge volume of data. In dev region its not reproducible. Anyway, I will have the DBA tomorrow and he could find something from your comments I hope.